# What is bad.list file in YOLO v4

Tags: computer-vision, object-detection, yolov4

after training YOLOV4, a file "bad.list" is made and containing the name of multiple images. What is the significance of this file and does it affect the trainig results and how can I fix this problem cause the images in bad.list are correctly annotated so I don't know what's the problem.

Thank you

Comment: Based on this code [here](https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet/issues/126#issue-248326887), it seems like, `bad.list` is generated when the image can't be loaded. It mostly shouldn't have to do anything with your labels (and considering the fact that you checked the labels)

Are all the images showing up in the `bad.list `file or only a few? Maybe the path for the images displayed in the `bad.list` file are not right, I would suggest you check these paths.  

[This](https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet/issues/979#issue-342034601) GitHub issue might also help

Comment: I am training YOLO on google colab so everytime the training stops because of the GPU, I rerun the training using the last weights saved, that's when an error occur and bad.list is created. So I have to change darknet in another folder. Does this affect the training?

Comment: I am not sure about that. How many files are there in the bad.list file and what is it's proportion in comparison with the whole training/validation set? If it's very few, it probably won't matter

Comment: yes it's few about 4 images, this only happens when the training stops and restarts

Comment: Can you try and check if it's the same set of 4 images every time? And are you sure that these exist in the path and are not corrupted and their annotations are correct? You might want to look into these causes

Comment: No they are not the same, they change everytime and sometimes I only have 1 file in bad.list, I checked the path and the annotation with labelimg, they seem correct. As I checked these images are the augmented images that i generated using roboflow. Maybe the objects are not very visible.

Comment: Not sure about the reason. You can consider posting an issue stating the details in the GitHub repo